# Find all homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}_{45}\to\Bbb{Z}_{36}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

So im trying to map $1$ (a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_{45}$) to an element in $\Bbb{Z}_{36}$. So what i did here was that, i know $|f(a)|$ must divide $|a|=45$, and also $|f(a)|$ must divide $|\Bbb{Z}_{36}|=36$; this narrows the possibilities of $|f(1)|$ to be $1, 3, 9$. Now since i have these, i know that the elements in $\Bbb{Z}_{36}$ that satisfy this will be such that either they are $36/1$ or $36/3$ or $36/9$, or $k$ such that $\gcd(k,36)=1,3,9$.

Now, correct me if im wrong in any of my assumptions above. The way I found my answers felt strange; do I have to just think of all possible numbers in $\Bbb{Z}_{36}$ that might satisfy these conditions? It feels like theres a good amount that do, which gives me the feeling I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: "|f(a)| must divide |a|=45" isn't really a restriction, since that's true for any element of $\Bbb Z_{45}$, si it happens automatically. It does tell you that it's useless to look for elements of order 2,4,6,12,18 and 36, though (because there are none).

Comment: I think you have more or less discovered the key constraints. The homomorphism is fully determined if you know $f(1)$. And because $\gcd(36,45)=9$ we must have $9f(1)=0$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{36}$. This leaves nine possibilities for the choice of $f(1)$, and you can surely list them all. Dealing separately with the choices of $f(1)$ that have order $3$ or $1$ is not necessary here, but doing so does give you a more complete picture of those homomorphisms because $|f(1)|$ gives you the size of the image.

Comment: I took the liberty to TeXify your post a bit. Not all of it was strictly necessary, but it does look better with subscripts in place. Click the edit button to see how we can use basic TeX-constructs here. If you are new to TeX, do study [this summary](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It's worth your while - trust me!

Answer (score 1):

From the Isomorphism Theorem you got correctly, that the cardinality of image must be a common divisor of $36$ and $45$, hence only $9, 3$ and $1$.

If the image is of cardinality $1$, it means that $f(1) = 0$, done.

Now remember/realize that for any divisor $k$ of $n$, there is precisely one subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ of cardinality $k$ and this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_k$, hence it has $\varphi(k)$ distinct generators. Let's use this:

if the image is of cardinality $3$, then it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (actually the subgroup with elements {0, 12, 24}), which has $\varphi(3) = 2$ generators (elements 12 and 24), so $f$ can map $1$ to any of them, hence 2 homomorphisms.

Similarly for the image of cardinality $9$ you get $\varphi(9) = 6$ different homomorphisms.

In total it looks like 9 homomorhisms.

Comment: ah, i didn't realize that was a general principle. why is it so that if the order of f(a)=n then they are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$_n?

Comment: forgot to tag you

Comment: @DavidHowie First realize that a subgroup of an abelian cyclic group $G$ is again cyclic: the first is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}_n$, so let's consider $H \leq G$ and take a minimal nonzero $k \in H$. Now, take $d \in H$ and divide $d$ by $k$ and consider the remainder $r<k$: $d =qk + r$, so $d - qk = r$, the left-hand side is in $H$, so $r$ must be too; but it is strictly smaller than $k$, which is minimal, hence $r$ is $0$ and $H$ is generated by $k$ and $H \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{ord(k)}$.